# Вероятность выпадения дубля

Tags: теория-вероятностей

Одновременно бросается 3 шестигранных кубика, какова вероятность выпадения одного дубля?

UPD: Под дублем имеется ввиду выпадение хотя бы двух одинаковых значений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сколько всего исходов (равновероятных)? `6^3 = 216`.

Сколько комбинаций со всеми различными значениями на кубиках? `6 * 5 * 4 = 120`.

Сколько комбинаций со все одинаковыми значениями на кубиках? `6`.

Сколько дублей, но не троек? `216 - 120 - 6 = 90`. Вероятность `90/216 = 5/12`

Сколько дублей включая тройки? `216 - 120 = 96`. Вероятность `96/216 = 4/9`.